# Substring each element of python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, substring, slice, series

Consider a data frame `df` with column `path`

```
/home/dir1/myfile1.txt
/home/anotherDir2/myfile2.txt
/home/anotherDir3/AnotherMyfile3.txt
```

I would like to split out the folder and filename part for each row.

I know that

`df.path.str.rfind('/')`

give me the last index of `/` **for the whole series**. I would want to apply this index result to the each row separately, but

`df.path.str.slice(0, df.path.str.rfind('/'))`

return all `NA`. It seems that `slice` expect a single integer parameter as `endposition` and not a series.

How would I achieve that in python ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the data frame that is used:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'path': ['/home/dir1/myfile1.txt', \
                            '/home/anotherDir2/myfile2.txt', \
                            '/home/anotherDir3/AnotherMyfile3.txt']})
```

You can use `apply()` to go through the rows of `df` and extract everything that is before the last `'/'`:

```
df.path.apply(lambda x: x[0:x.rfind('/')])
```

Which returns:

```
0           /home/dir1
1    /home/anotherDir2
2    /home/anotherDir3
Name: path, dtype: object
```

Similarily, you can do the same to extract everything that is after the last `'/'`:

```
df.path.apply(lambda x: x[(x.rfind('/') + 1):len(x)])
```

Which returns:

```
0           myfile1.txt
1           myfile2.txt
2    AnotherMyfile3.txt
Name: path, dtype: object
```

If you want to get both, folder and file, you can use a function like this that splits a string by `'/'` and returns the last 2 elements:

```
def split_path(path):
    folder_file = path.split('/')[-2:]
    return(pd.Series({'folder': folder_file[0], 'file': folder_file[1]}))
```

Then you can `apply()` it and add the 2 columns to your df:

```
pd.concat([df, df.path.apply(split_path)], axis=1)
```

Which returns:

```
                                   path                file       folder
0                /home/dir1/myfile1.txt         myfile1.txt         dir1
1         /home/anotherDir2/myfile2.txt         myfile2.txt  anotherDir2
2  /home/anotherDir3/AnotherMyfile3.txt  AnotherMyfile3.txt  anotherDir3
```